# how to dynamically export data from excel to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i simply export data to MySQL database.but i got a problem when some column are disorder as database.

pl z help me to export database dynamically  in MySQL.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Use phpMyAdmin to create the database and create a table with the exact same column names as your excel doc. Save the excel doc as a CSV comma delimited file, then follow these steps using phpMyAdmin's import:

1. Check if your cvs file’s column name match your table column name
2. Browse your required .csv file (while import tab is selected)
3. Select CSV using LOAD DATA options
4. Tick ‘ON’ for Replace table data with file
5. Put , in terminated by box type field
6. Put ” in enclosed by box field
7. Put \ in escaped by box field
8. Put auto in Lines terminated by box field
9. In Column names box, type all the column names seperated by comma. i.e column1,column2,column3 (this must match with your table and csv column header).
10. Tick ‘ON’ for Use LOCAL keyword